# Typescript always creates app.js in the root folder

Tags: typescript

I read this thread on Microsoft typescript GitHub repo

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10585

Based on the recommendations here I wrote the following tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "app.js",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include":["src"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", 
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

As you can see that I have specified the "include", "exclude" element which the thread above talked about.

```
 > as a fix, either make the outDir another folder, specify a list of "files", "include" or "exclude"
```

but still when I do either `tsc --watch` or `tsc --build tsconfig.json --watch` it always creates the `app.js` and `app.js.map` in the root folder and not in the `dist` as I configured

What was I not able to read in that thread?

Comment: I think you'll want to remove `outFile` for this to work, or if you intend to compile everything into 1 target file, set it to `dist/app.js`

Comment: So why doesn't the compiler tell me that I can't use both?

Comment: I can't answer that. Open a ticket if you think the behavior is wrong.